# Conditional random field, concept and terminology clarification needed: markov order, transition, connectivity

Tags: machine-learning, mallet, crf

I am using Mallet to use Conditional Random Field. From my understanding, CRF has a few kinds of markov order depending on how nodes are connected. In the figure, it's the three quarter order, the first order, and the second order from the top. [image]

1. **Concept check:** I'm basically confused about the terms, "markov order" and "connectivity" and "transition" because they all seem to refer to the same concept. I believe that A node can be transitioned to another node if there is an edge connecting them. Is this it or am I missing something?
2. **The order parameters** In Mallet, I can set the parameters on which markov order I want to use, and I thought it would take 1,2, 0.75... but instead it takes two parameters and they explain as "main and backoff order". What does this mean?
3. My task resembles a sequential tagging, which is why I tried to use CRF. The classification task I am doing highly correlates to the previous node's classification result. When I used SVM for this task, I included "Previous node label" feature and did a two-phase learning, where I first trained SVM using the truth data for "previous node label" and then trained another model using the prediction result of the first classifier. But in CRF, if I use second order, which includes previous node's label, would this kind of learning or using this feature be unnecessary? I hope I'm explaining this clearly.